# Excluding shared editor templates from project in Visual Studio doesn't work

Tags: asp.net-mvc, visual-studio-2012

I want to run my ASP.net MVC project without using a particular shared editor template that has errors
eg.

*~\Views\Shared\EditorTemplates\String.cshtml*

But even when I right click and exclude it from the project, it is used when the project is run and it errors out. What should I do to tell Visual Studio to ignore this template?

I'm using Visual Studio 2012 Professional.

Comment: can't you just delete it instead of excluding it?

Comment: I want to fix the errors in the future. Even after fixing the errors, I want to toggle and see what the site looks like with and without the custom editor template.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to keep the file, but not have ASP.Net MVC use it, rename the file. Call it `-String.cshtml`.

DisplayTemplates and EditorTemplates are looked up in their respective directories, matching filenames to the type they are used on. When you exclude them from the project they are physically still present and found, therefore still used.